# Oracle 10g dump file push into Oracle 11g database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-10g

Currently when executing the `imp` command with the following parameters:  `file=my.dmp log=my.log fromuser=myuser touser=myuser`

The following errors occur:

```
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 12560 encountered
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

However, `tnsping` successfully looks up the values in my tnsnames.ora file.  My question is does the dump file created in 10g cause an issue on import into 11g or is this error something else that I am unable to diagnose.

Comment: TNSPING only tells you the host is reachable. It tells you just about *squat* about the database. The best way to determine if your database is up externally is to see if you can simply connect via SQL*PLUS; if you can't, then your database is either down or your listener is down/refusing connections. On the server check lsnrctl status to determine listener state, and on the db, ps|grep for oracle or sqlplus in (it'll tell you if it is down).

Comment: Are you using `exp` from your 10g ORACLE_HOME and `imp` from your 11g ORACLE_HOME?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem might very well have to do with incorrect versions or wrong default connection. Make sure that you use the exp utility from the 10g installation and the imp utility from the 11g installation.
Also make sure that the environment variables like ORACLE_HOME are correct and that PATH is adjusted for the correct ORACLE_HOME/bin

How does your connect string look like?
Is your TNS_ADMIN variable defined? (if not, you might need to have multiple tnsnames.ora files in place, or tnsnames.ora is in a platform specific location (/etc, /var/opt/oracle etc.)) tnsping shows where it gets the sqlnet.ora (next to tnsnames.ora) from.

Even better is to start using expdp and impdp. You can use impdp to directly import your data in the 11g database, using a datasbase link.

Comment: +1 for datapump. A little more painful to set up if you have to do file exports (create the directory in oracle), but way better than imp/exp, especially when doing the complete database.

Answer (score 7):

A 10g file can be loaded into an 11g database. It is throwing a networking error and TNSPING doesn't go all the way to the database, just as far as the listener port. I suspect you'd have the same trouble connecting via SQLPLUS.

Check your tnsnames.ora and that the database and listener are available

Comment: hmm I will look into this, thanks for the info.