# Oracle 10g dump file into Oracle 11g database

Tags: oracle, import, export, datapump

I went through this link for my answer to the same question. I was not sure if i could continue in the same link, so created a new question.

[Oracle 10g dump file push into Oracle 11g database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/oracle-10g-dump-file-push-into-oracle-11g-database)

Sorry if I am wrong.

When I used `imp`  with the following parameters:

```
file=my.dmp log=my.log fromuser=myuser touser=myuser statistics=none, ignore=y, full=y
```

I got the following errors:

```
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 12560 encountered
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Also this error message was there

> the procedure entry point longjmp could not be located in the dynamic link library ORAUTS.DLL

The database and devsuite home are installed on Windows in two different drives. I found some references saying I should run the datapump import commands from the 11g home, with this:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1
set ORACLE_SID=ORCL11R1
```

I am new to this Oracle database. Should this command be run in command prompt, since the installation is done on Windows, is it "set ORACLE_HOME"?

Any suggestion on this would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

That error is most likely due to incorrect environment settings indeed, probably your `PATH` is mixed up too.

In a command prompt, assuming that your Oracle 11g home is indeed as you posted above, run:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1
set ORACLE_SID=ORCL11R1
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Make sure you can connect with `sqlplus`, then start `imp`.

(Do consider using the `expdp`/`impdp` Data pump tools instead though. `imp`/`exp` are essentially deprecated in 11g.)